# How can you spot what trigonometric substitution to use in an integral?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

So I seem to be coming across a lot of integrals requiring trigonometric substitutions.

However, it's becoming tiring, because I have no idea how to spot what substitution should be used - i.e. always having to resort to the internet to find out.

Does anyone have any tips for spotting/deciding what substitution to use in such integrals?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Similarly, this works for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{...}}$.

Basically, anything that uses any of the following trig/hyperbolic identities (or re-arrangements thereof):

$sin^2{\theta
}+cos^2{\theta}\equiv1$;

$cosh^2{u}-sinh^2{u}\equiv1$;

$1+tan^2{\theta}\equiv sec^2{\theta}$.

Comment: In short, you're substituting so that you can use the pythagorian identities to simplify the problem -- so pick the substitution that makes the pythagorean identity appear in your integral!